# Getting AJAX to not load a new page after submitting a form and instead render a partial view or nothing

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm in a bit of a bind here, I am trying to submit a form using ajax, all goes well and dandy until after the server has done it's thing, it decides to load to the action onto a new page, which is exactly what I do not want.

Here is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(int id, string trainingProgramId, FormCollection form, User user)
    {
        //Do Some action

        return null;
    }
```

In a different controller I have it set up to do $return PartialView(model);

this is the JQuery code that I am using.

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if (nextquestion()) { //check if posting can proceed
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    $('#cases:last-child').insertAfter(response);
                },
                error: function (data) { }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In all cases I am being redirected to a different url after performing the operation. Which is not the intention, especially if my intention might be to load more stuff into the page.

I've been tring everything, a bunch of solutions, but once my controller does a return statement the page automatically reloads to $/Submit

I have added $        @Scripts.Render("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"); to my scripts

From any other example I am finding this should work as I want it to, by remaining on the same page, however I am finding it difficult to understand who is responsible for changing the page either way. When I return my PartialView, a completely new page loads with the model as I've had it set up for the Partial View to be inserted originally.

Anyone care to explain what is going on or why my code is wrong?

I can't find it after a whole day of trying to debug.

Comment: Replace `nextquestion()` with `true`. If your script is blowing up in there you might not be doing `preventDefault()`.

Comment: The great thing about `e.preventDefault()` over `return false`  is that you can do it at the top of a handler like this, such that it's far more likely (I hesitate to say guaranteed) to suppress natural form submission. Like @Jasen, I would suspect `nextquestion()`.

Comment: Check out the response in console. Could the partial you are injecting coming over with a meta or javascript redirect?

Comment: Upon waking up, apparently, now it's working "better" I somehow managed to fix up the code.

Comment: One of them worked as is, which was odd, as it was the more complicated one controller wise. So I knew I couldn't blame Controller code cause the non functioning one was gutted to only have `return null` in it.

Turns out the non functioning one had a stray `datatype: "JSON"` in it which for some reason broke everything. Removing it for some reason made it work. I also ended up moving some of the hide and shows I had in `nextquestions()` to the success function of my AJAX.